# Override a method in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I am trying to add extra code to a method in ( odoo11 / hr_payroll ). what i have done is copied and pasted the whole code and added the extra code in it, but when the method get executed, it get executed two time which proves what i have done is wrong.

I am looking for a solution butter than coping and pasting the whole code.

So here what I want to add in the base method:

Base method:

```
   if debit_account_id:
                  debit_line = (0, 0, {
                      'name': line.name,
                      'partner_id': line._get_partner_id(credit_account=False),
                      'account_id': debit_account_id,
                      'journal_id': slip.journal_id.id,
                      'date': date,
                      'debit': amount > 0.0 and amount or 0.0,
                      'credit': amount < 0.0 and -amount or 0.0,
                      'analytic_account_id': line.salary_rule_id.analytic_account_id.id,
                      'tax_line_id': line.salary_rule_id.account_tax_id.id,
                  })
                  line_ids.append(debit_line)
                  debit_sum += debit_line[2]['debit'] - debit_line[2]['credit']
```

Inherited method:

```
  @api.multi
  def action_payslip_done(self):
      res = super(PayslipBills, self).action_payslip_done()

      if debit_account_id:
                  debit_line = (0, 0, {
                      'name': line.name,
                      'partner_id': line._get_partner_id(credit_account=False),
                      'account_id': debit_account_id,
                      'journal_id': slip.journal_id.id,
                      'x_account_no': x_debit_account, # extra
                      'x_jtag': [(6, 0, x_tags)], # extra
                      'x_jtag_option': [(6, 0, x_tags_option)], # extra
                      'date': date,
                      'debit': amount > 0.0 and amount or 0.0,
                      'credit': amount < 0.0 and -amount or 0.0,
                      'analytic_account_id': line.salary_rule_id.analytic_account_id.id,
                      'tax_line_id': line.salary_rule_id.account_tax_id.id,
                  })
                  line_ids.append(debit_line)
                  debit_sum += debit_line[2]['debit'] - debit_line[2]['credit']

      return res
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid problems with other modules that could inherit and redefine the same module and method I would keep the call to the original method with supper(...) and right after that update those records with the extra fields and values that you need to add, for example if the values of x_whatever are always the same for that recordset and regardless of being credit or debit lines you may try something like:

```
class PayslipBills(models.Model):
      _inherit = 'hr.payslip'

      (... define new fields and new methods...)

      @api.multi
      def action_payslip_done(self):
          res = super(PayslipBills, self).action_payslip_done()
          for record in res:
              for lines in record.line_ids
                  # add values to the extra fields...
                  lines.write({'x_account_no': x_debit_account,
                     'x_jtag': [(6, 0, x_tags)],
                     'x_jtag_option': [(6, 0, x_tags_option)],
                      })
          return res
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some interesting information your question is missing. Firstly this original method (module hr_payroll) is already overridden by hr_payroll_account. And secondly this first override by hr_payroll_account is really messed_up in way you can't override by trying your change/extension.

So the only solution is to completely rewrite/override the original method WITHOUT calling super. Beware the fact business logic in two already existing methods! You have to copy both logics to your new methods.

I don't like those solution, but it's the only possible one (that i know of).

Comment: Haha thanks ;-) there is always something to learn. But he is trying to change a little part within a 150 lines method. The original one is like 3 lines. So your answer is very interesting, but won't help is this special case.

Comment: I think I was wrong but still there is a way because we can simulate the call of super in python. and believe me I always loved your answers. The goal of the answer is there is a way to skip some method in Odoo too and this is why I love python

Comment: checkout my edits this worked for me perfectly and it doesn't require a lot of coding ^^

Comment: mmmmmm but still a problem with my method too this will not work if we want to skip a method that is in the middle. is there a way in python to get super of super?!!!